# Using FLAC/MP3 metadata's value to rename a file?

Tags: bash, shell, mp3, mv, flac

I have access to a list of mp3 files with randomised names, from a free licence project providing wikipedia with audio files for words. [Chinese list of files here](http://packs.shtooka.net/cmn-caen-tan/flac/) / [here](http://shtooka.net/download.php), and [a sample file here](http://packs.shtooka.net/cmn-caen-tan/flac/cmn-0a0a8a8b.flac)

Each files, however, also contains valuable metadata:

```
$avconv -i ./audio.flac 2>&1
>Metadata:
    TITLE           : 高低
    LICENSE         : Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 U.S
    COPYRIGHT       : (c) 2009 Yue Tan
    ARTIST          : Tan
    DATE            : 2009-07-08
    GENRE           : Speech
    SWAC_LANG       : cmn
    SWAC_TEXT       : 高低
    SWAC_ALPHAIDX   : gāodī
    SWAC_SPEAK_NAME : Tan
    SWAC_SPEAK_GENDER: F
    SWAC_SPEAK_BIRTH_YEAR: 1978
    SWAC_SPEAK_LANG : zho
    SWAC_SPEAK_LANG_REGION: Liaoning
    SWAC_SPEAK_LIV_COUNTRY: FR
    SWAC_SPEAK_LIV_TOWN: Caen
    SWAC_PRON_PHON  : gāodī
    SWAC_COLL_SECTION: HSK niveau IV
    SWAC_COLL_LICENSE: Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 U.S
    SWAC_COLL_COPYRIGHT: (c) 2009 Yue Tan
    SWAC_TECH_DATE  : 2009-07-08
    SWAC_TECH_SOFT  : Shtooka Recorder/1.3
  Duration: 00:00:01.25, bitrate: 392 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16
```

**How could I get the metadata `SWAC_ALPHAIDX`'s value as a Shell variable** so I could rename my files accordingly ?

So I may do something like

```
$mv -input ./cmn-0a0a8a8b.flac -output ./new/cmn-$ALPHAIDX.flac 
# ouput being cmn-gāodī.flac
```

---

**Edit:** answer with other metadata will be accepted as well, no need to manage the special characters of gāodī if bugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse out the data you want from the info dump, capture it in a variable, and then use that:

```
for file in ./*.flac
do
  alphaidx=$(avconv -i "$file" 2>&1 | sed -ne 's/.*SWAC_ALPHAIDX *: //p')
  mv "$file" "./cmn-$alphaidx.flac"
done
```

Work with diacritic characters such `gāodī (SWAC_ALPHAIDX)` or CJK such `高低 (SWAC_TEXT)`.

**Note:** it's a renaming function, not a copy-rename function.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Answer validation granted, and a big thanks.